# link two lists of different types together

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program that lets user put in some cities and the temperature in the city. Later the list with the temperatures will sort itself so I can get the coldest and the hottest city in the list. But the problem is that only the list with the temperatures will get sorted. This makes the cities have different temperatures than before.

So can I link the two lists together so when a temperature in the second list changes place the city that originally got the temperature will change place to?

I’m kind of new to programming.

Thanks.

Comment: if it sounds logical theres normally a way to do it.. you should try posting what you have tried

Comment: Though I agree it's not an overly well-written question (the description of the problem is a bit abstract and confusing, given that you already seem to have some concrete code), I'm not sure what the close votes are for ... I have seen far more disastrous in here. Anyway, the way to go would probably be one list, items of which store a city name *and* the temperatures.

Comment: Not enough people are nice to programming. If you work with two lists, how would you know, which city is connected to which temperature? You need one object to hold both values together. Either make your own class for that or in this case, maybe `Tuple<string,decimal>` will suffice. Now you have one `List<Tuple<string,decimal>` which you can order by one or the other. `list.OrderBy(x => x.Item1)` or `list.OrderBy(x => x.Item2)`

Comment: @Elgon, next time you post your problem: 1. put some code that you have tried but isn't working. 2. provide error details (if applicable) 3. put some effort in wording your problem statement better.

Comment: OP seems to have a valid problem, for which he seems to have tried something. So as O.R. Mapper noted, it's not as worse as it has been made. He just didn't word his problem well and didn't post the code. Considering, he's new to SO, IMO, we should help him by telling what's wrong rather than simply downvoting and discouraging. Is there some FAQ which we can point to in such scenarios?

Comment: @Elgon Don't you think it's time to accept an answer, or at least write a comment that explains why none of the answers deserve to be accepted (maybe we misunderstood your question)?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to put City name and City temperature together, like

```
public class City
{
    public string Name;
    public double Temperature;
    // etc.
}
```

Then create a `List<City>` and whenever you need to sort that list according to a specific field, you can use Linq (`using System.Linq;`) to sort the list

```
List<City> sortedList = cityList.OrderBy(city => city.Temperature).ToList();
           // or if you want the list sorted the other way around:
           sortedList = cityList.OrderByDescending(city => city.Temperature).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

In case you're working with a .NET version prior to 3.5, there won't be any Linq, so you'll need a few alternatives:

- If you only need one sorting order, you can implement the `IComparable` interface

  ```
  public class City : IComparable
  {
      public int CompareTo(object obj)
      {
          City other = obj as City;
          if (other == null)
              // obj was not a City, so this should throw an exception in my opinion
              throw new ArgumentException;

          return this.Temperature.CompareTo(other.Temperature);
      }
  }
  ```

  Then you can sort the list with `cityList.Sort()`
- Or if you want to be able to sort the list sometimes by temperature, sometimes by name, you'll need to work with delegates

  ```
  cityList.Sort(delegate (City a, City b)
                {
                    // -1 => a <  b
                    //  0 => a == b
                    //  1 => a >  b
                    return a.Name.CompareTo(b.Name);
                });
  // cityList is now sorted by name

  cityList.Sort(delegate (City a, City b)
                {
                    // -1 => a <  b
                    //  0 => a == b
                    //  1 => a >  b
                    return a.Temperature.CompareTo(b.Temperature);
                });
  // cityList is now sorted by temperature
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have structure to hold both city and temperature together.. e.g.

```
public class CityInfo 
{ 
  public string CityName {get; set;}
  public float Temperature {get; set;}
}
```

Then create a list of this class.

```
List<CityInfo> citiInfos = new List<CityInfo>();
```

Then you can sort based:

on city name:

```
var sortedByCity = citiInfos.OrderBy(cityInfo => cityInfo.CityName);
```

on temperature:

```
var sortedByTemp = citiInfos.OrderBy(cityInfo => cityInfo.Temperature);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you create an object containing the city information and the corresponding temperature for example

```
class City
{
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public int Inhabitants {get; private set;}
    public float Temperature {get; private set;}

    public City (string name, int inhabitants, float temp)
    {
        Name = name;
        Inhabitants = inhabitants;
        Temperature = temperature;
    }
}
```

and then create a `List<City>`, add your cities with

```
cityListName.Add(new City("CityName",9000,16.5));
...
```

then you can sort this `List` by temperature with `cityListName.OrderBy((city)=>city.Temperature)`

I hope this helped.
If you have further questions feel free to ask.